# Как в PHPExcel считать информацию из ячейки содержащую ссылку?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, гиперссылка

Необходимо разобрать Excel файл в некоторых ячейках которого содержатся ссылки. Требуется получить для таких ячеек ссылки в формата HTML(ну или как то иначе, лишь бы можно было получить как URL ссылки так и анкор).

Сейчас файл разбирается примерно следующим кодом:

```
$xls = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($fileAddress);
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
$excelDataAr = $sheet->toArray();
```

Таким кодом от ячеек с ссылками в массив $excelDataAr попадают только анкоры(то есть текст ссылки). Подскажите способ как получить URL гиперссылок из ячеек, а лучше настройку(если такая существует) чтобы в результате выполнения $sheet->toArray(); ячейкам которые содержат ссылки соответствовали бы элементы массива содержащие их в виде HTML кода.

Comment: Можно таким образом `$sheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A1")->getHyperlink()->getUrl()`